# Error in loading Glove vectors using TorchText on Kaggle Kernel

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

I am trying to load the Glove embedding vectors in kaggle kernel using TorchText lib.

```
from torchtext import vocab
vec = vocab.Vectors('glove.6B.100d.txt', '../input/glove6b100dtxt/')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '../input/glove6b100dtxt/glove.6B.100d.txt.pt'
```

Adding screenshot for more clarification:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on under the hood there. But obviously torchtext tries to save some processed results "...100.txt.pt". As your file system does not allow for writing operations you get an error. So the easiest fix would be using a file system that allows the lib to create new files.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, I just added an extra argument for the output file like this: vec = vocab.Vectors('../input/glove6b100dtxt/glove.6B.100d.txt', '../output/kaggle/working/') and it worked

Comment: Great! You can post an answer to your own question if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you are using glove embeddings as part of the input from other datasets. You don't have the right access to the input folder so the workaround is as follows :

##### Now we will load the Glove Embedding and move it out to the working directory

```
!cp -r ../input/glove-embeddings/ ../kaggle/working/glove-embeddings
```

Once moved, change the location of access

```
vec = vocab.Vectors('glove.6B.100d.txt', '../kaggle/working/glove-embeddings')
```